# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column is of type cidr but expression is of type character

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to  load a scala spark data frame into postgres SQL table. I have read the data from a csv with specific schema. But it throws exception below. I have added `stringtype=unspecified` both while writing data frame and in jdbc url but no luck.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "range" is of type cidr but expression is of type character
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

my code is given below.

```
  val session = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("MyLoad").getOrCreate()

    val mySchema = StructType(Seq(
      StructField("range", StringType, false),
      StructField("flat", IntegerType, true)))

    val myDf = session.sqlContext.read.format("csv")
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .option("escape", "\"")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "")
      .schema(mySchema)
      .load("Path to CSV")
   
    myDf.write
      .format("jdbc")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .option("url", "jdbc url")
      .option("dbtable", "mytable")
      .option("user", "myuser")
      .option("password", "password")
      .option("stringtype", "unspecified")
      .save()
```

Any other changes need to do?
Please help me out..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939841/writing-to-a-postgresql-cidr-column-with-spark-jdbc.

Comment: .option("stringtype", "unspecified") added this option. But its changing the datatype of the table into text